# LibreOffice PPA version has incompabilities with Unity, how to solve them?

Tags: unity, libreoffice, ppa

I have intermittent problems running LibreOffice 4.1.1.2 (from the PPA) on Precise 12.04.03. Sometimes when I am either opening or closing the document, the screen flashes and the unity panel disappears.

I am unable to Alt-tab between windows and sometimes my keyboard is not responsive (although Alt-Fx is able to get me to a console login).

if I keep a terminal window open, I am able to close windows down using my mouse and restart unity from the command line (if my keyboard is responsive).

Any ideas on a fix?

I purged the libreoffice-gtk package as per suggestions in other posts, to no effect.

In addition, when I run unity from the terminal, the crash generates these messages (which is meaningless to me, but may help others):

```
WARN  2013-09-05 11:41:09 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children:
No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.view' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application0xbf9060

ERROR 2013-09-05 11:41:11 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN 2013-09-05 11:42:06 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path:
No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.application' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application0xb8aa70
WARN  2013-09-05 11:42:06 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children:
No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.view' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application0xb8aa70

WARN  2013-09-05 11:42:06 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path:
No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.application' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application0xb8ae80
WARN  2013-09-05 11:42:06 unity.gdk <unknown>:0 compiz:
Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

UPDATE 2:
I suspect my issue is related to this bug, as I un-maximised the screen and have not had a problem. No workaround available yet, it seems :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/829384

Answer (score 0):

You can install Libreoffice in a simple way.

First remove the package.

```
sudo apt-get purge libre-office*
```

Download the [latest libreoffice main installer](http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/deb-x86_64/4.1.1/en-US/LibreOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz). 
Untar and select all the packages with `CTRL+A.`

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Drag and drop all selected packages from file browser to the terminal and press enter.

It will prompt you for your password and start installing the latest libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

Could you by chance have these problems only when opening / saving a file on a samba (or cifs) share (usually a distant windows file server)?

If yes you may experience the (not fixed) bug reported at various places

- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58236
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1070963

My current workaround is to open a blank/local openoffice file first... and then work as usual without experiencing this crash.

hope this helps.

Comment: No, not SMB. See my update 2 on the original post.